# Resource not found 404 response code and redirect to custom page using web.config file

Tags: asp.net

I know how to use custom errors in asp.net web.config file when a non existent .aspx page is requested by the user like following;

```
       <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error.aspx">
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="/error.aspx"/>
        </customErrors>
```

and is working fine for me, but when I tried to access non existent static resource such as test.htm, I am served with blue screen of death by IIS.

If somebody knows how to redirect user to customized page say resourcenotfound.aspx when a non existing resource is requested by the user, then please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: blue screen of death? u mean yellow screen of death?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where you are implementing your custom errors only affects things running through the ASP.NET pipeline (.aspx files for instance).  By default, IIS does not send request for static files (.html, .htm, .css, .js) through the ASP.NET pipeline.  As a result, you are getting the standard IIS error page (the blue one, yellow ones are for ASP.NET errors).

In order to override the IIS standard error files for **Any** response, you need to use the `<httpErrors>` element in the `<system.webServer>` element.

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
         <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
         <error statusCode="404" path="Error.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
      </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Details for this answer were taken from the [official IIS website](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors) and this [blog entry](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2011/5/custom-404-and-error-pages-for-asp-net-and-static-files/)

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for!